# 2 Rows are overlapped and collapsed into one only

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

My React Native 0.66 app has a component showing images in square grid. There can be 1-9 image grids with max of 3 images in one row and 3 images in one column. The size of image grids is always `screen_width x screen_width`. Here is a code handling 4 images:

```
case 4:
            return (
                <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"column", width:"100%", height:screen_width, position:"relative", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>
                    <RowX2 idx={0} wdh={half} picsource={pics}/>. //1st row with 2 images
                    <RowX2 idx={2} wdh={half} picsource={pics}/>. //2nd row with 2 images
                </View>. //problem is that there is only one row with 2 images showing
                );

const RowX2 = ({picsource, idx, wdh}) => {
        console.log("RowX2 idx ", idx);
        console.log("RowX2 wdh ", wdh);
        console.log("RowX2 picsource ", picsource);
        return (           
            <View style={styles.row, {flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}} >
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(picsource[idx])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                /> 
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(picsource[idx+1])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx+1}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                />                   
            </View>
        );
    };
```

The code used to be working fine. But today I found that all 4 images grid collapse into one row with only 2 images showing. I have no clue how this happened.